# plsql procedure repetitive line of code. trying to make in better way

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a scenario. If user pass the parameter `Entity_type` then you need to insert data for that `entity` (`table`) only. If he doesn't pass any parameter then you need to insert data for all the required tables into one table.

so We have table `DYNAMICENTITYGTT` which will take data from `Item` table if it is passed, `org` table if it is passed. But it will take data from both the table if `Entity_type` parameter is null in proc..

Also it will store another column depending on the type of `UPDATE_MODE` means add or delete.
Target table is same. source table and its column name are different but type are same.

I have written below procedure for the same.

I am only requesting is there anyway to make this code better. I mean can this be written in more smarter way? Because I am repeating multiple lines. I have given example of 2 entities but there are 7 so code would be huge.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure UPDATE_DYNAMIC_ENTITY(ENTITY_TYPE varchar2 default null,UPDATE_MODE varchar2)
Is
x number;
BEGIN
IF UPPER(entity_type)='ITEM' then
    if upper(UPDATE_MODE)='DELETE' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,Item_id,item_name,item_desc,'delete' from ITEMDE;
    ELSIF lower(UPDATE_MODE)='add' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,Item_id,item_name,item_desc,'add' from ITEMDE;
    END IF;
ELSIF UPPER(entity_type)='ORG' then
    if upper(UPDATE_MODE)='DELETE' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'delete' from ORGDE;
    ELSIF lower(UPDATE_MODE)='add' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'add' from ORGDE;
    END IF;
ELSE
   if upper(UPDATE_MODE)='DELETE' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,Item_id,item_name,item_desc,'delete' from ITEMDE;
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'delete' from ORGDE;
    ELSIF lower(UPDATE_MODE)='add' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,Item_id,item_name,item_desc,'add' from ITEMDE;
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'add' from ORGDE;
   END IF;
   
END IF;
END UPDATE_DYNAMIC_ENTITY;
```

Comment: Entity_type value will come from parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically I see two inserts with two variables determining its content. You are inserting from select statement, therefore you can manipulate these selects to return no values when conditions are not as expected.

For parameter `p_update_mode` it is easy, if it contains value "delete" insert "delete", if it contains value "add" insert "add".

For parameter `p_entity_type` we insert from both selects when its value is "NULL", only from `itemde` table if value is "ITEM" and only from `orgde` table if value is "ORG".

Now in case there is some invalid value in `p_entity_type` none of the selects will produce data as we only recognise "NULL", "ITEM" and "ORG". But for parameter `p_update_mode` we directly modify the value and use it in insert, therefore it would be better to perform some check if the input value is valid for us.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_dynamic_entity(p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                  p_update_mode VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  IF lower(p_update_mode) NOT IN ('add', 'delete')
  THEN
    RAISE VALUE_ERROR; -- maybe use raise_application_error for more details about problem
  END IF;
  --
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    SELECT upper(NVL(p_entity_type, 'ITEM')), item_id, item_name, item_desc, lower(p_update_mode)
      FROM itemde
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = 'ITEM'
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
  --
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    SELECT upper(NVL(p_entity_type, 'ORG')), org_id, org_name, org_desc, lower(p_update_mode)
      FROM orgde
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = 'ORG'
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

As you write you have 7 entities therefore this approach would lead to have 7 inserts, as I believe (and let me know if I am wrong) each entity has its own set of data in different tables.

There is also possibility to join all these tables and make it into single insert as example below, and every new entity would mean only adding new select into `WITH` part of the statement. But I am not sure about performance in this case. That would depend on how full your tables are.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_dynamic_entity(p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                  p_update_mode VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  IF lower(p_update_mode) NOT IN ('add', 'delete')
  THEN
    RAISE VALUE_ERROR; -- maybe use raise_application_error for more details about problem
  END IF;
  --
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORG' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc
        FROM orgde
      -- NEXT entity table
      )
    SELECT upper(entity_type), data_id, data_name, data_desc, lower(p_update_mode)
      FROM data_view
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = entity_type
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

And even if this gets messy for you, you can create a `VIEW` where you do the `UNION`s and remove that `WITH` from `PROCEDURE` and with new entities adding selects into `VIEW` instead of `PROCEDURE`.

Comment: I am not sure if tables `itemde` and `orgde` contain column `entity_type` as there is no information about that in original post. OP will have to provide such information and I will adjust my reply accordingly if necessary.

Comment: thanks a lot.  entity_type will come as parameter. it is in target table but not in source table.

Comment: thanks a lot. I also need to add , add or delete value in queries. this value also doesnt exist with source table but it is Action in target table.

Comment: It is already there. Look for `p_update_mode` parameter.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question related to this? little extended requirement? If you are Ok..I can write a question and will ping here the link

Comment: Feel free to ask here and if it will be a larger piece of cake, I'll let you know if new question would be better.

Comment: thank you so much.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63512622/optimizing-code-in-pl-sql-making-it-to-proper-code-is-running-but-not-proper