# Optimizing code in PL/SQL. Making it to proper. Code is running but not proper

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I have 3 set of tables.
Source table

```
ORGDE(ORG_ID,ORG_NAME,ORG_DESC,CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATE_DATE)       
ITEMDE(ITEM_ID,ITEM_NAME,ITEM_DESC,CREATION_DATE,LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
```

Target table

```
DYNAMICENTITYGTT(ENTITY_TYPE,ENTITY_ID,ENTITY_CODE,SYNONYMS,ACTION)
```

Condition table

```
BATCH_RUN_DETAILS(ENTITY_TYPE,LAST_RUN_DATE,MAX_LAST_UPDATE_DATE)
```

We have to insert data in DYNAMICENTITYGTT from ORGDE and ITEMDE.
Action in `DYNAMICENTITYGTT will be 'update' where CREATION_DATE>max_last_update_date`
Action in `DYNAMICENTITYGTT will be 'add' where CREATION_DATE<max_last_update_date`
if p_entity_type is present then it will insert data for that entity else it will insert for both tables.

I have written below code. i want to improve it and make it better.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure UPDATE_DYNAMIC_ENTITY(P_ENTITY_TYPE varchar2 default null,P_UPDATE_MODE varchar2)
IS
BEGIN
IF UPPER(P_UPDATE_MODE)='INCREMENTAL'
THEN
 IF UPPER(p_entity_type)='ORG' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select P_Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'add' from ORGDE where creation_date>(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
     INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select P_Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'update' from ORGDE where creation_date<(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
 ELSIF UPPER(p_entity_type)='ITEM' then
      INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select P_Entity_type,item_id,item_name,item_desc,'add' from ITEMDE where creation_date>(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
     INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select P_Entity_type,item_id,item_name,item_desc,'update' from ITEMDE where creation_date<(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
 ELSIF P_ENTITY_TYPE=NULL THEN
     --Reading from org
     INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select p_Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'add' from ORGDE where creation_date>(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
     INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select p_Entity_type,ORG_id,org_name,org_desc,'update' from ORGDE where creation_date<(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
     --reading from item
     INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select p_Entity_type,item_id,item_name,item_desc,'add' from ITEMDE where creation_date>(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
     INSERT INTO DYNAMICENTITYGTT(Entity_type,Entity_id,Entity_code,Synonyms,Action) select p_Entity_type,item_id,item_name,item_desc,'update' from ITEMDE where creation_date<(select max_last_update_date from BATCH_RUN_DETAILS where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE);
  END IF;
END IF;
END UPDATE_DYNAMIC_ENTITY;
```

Can you please suggest improvement on code.

Comment: Just a note `ELSIF P_ENTITY_TYPE=NULL THEN` will always result in false. Correct condition would be `ELSIF P_ENTITY_TYPE IS NULL THEN`.

Comment: @KayaNatsumi thanks a lot. I approved the changed. Could you please help me to modify the above code in betteer way?

Comment: Same problem with `where ENTITY_TYPE=P_ENTITY_TYPE`. And that `select p_Entity_type` can be null is probably not intended either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be similar to answer before at [plsql procedure repetitive line of code. trying to make in better way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63507869/plsql-procedure-repetitive-line-of-code-trying-to-make-in-better-way/63508064).

What we do now is add `JOIN` to table containing `batch_run_details` and case that will determine for each row what action it has to insert based on `creation_date` and `max_last_update_date`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_dynamic_entity(p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                  p_update_mode VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  IF lower(p_update_mode) <> 'incremental'
  THEN
    RETURN; -- Do nothing if incorrect mode
  END IF;
  --
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    SELECT upper(NVL(p_entity_type, 'ITEM')),
           t.item_id,
           t.item_name,
           t.item_desc,
           CASE
             WHEN t.creation_date > b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'update'
             WHEN t.creation_date < b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'add'
           END
      FROM itemde t
      JOIN batch_run_details b
        ON b.entity_type = 'ITEM'
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = 'ITEM'
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
  --
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    SELECT upper(NVL(p_entity_type, 'ORG')),
           t.org_id,
           t.org_name,
           t.org_desc,
           CASE
             WHEN t.creation_date > b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'update'
             WHEN t.creation_date < b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'add'
           END
      FROM orgde t
      JOIN batch_run_details b
        ON b.entity_type = 'ORG'
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = 'ORG'
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

And just for completion from previous post, single insert version as well:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_dynamic_entity(p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                  p_update_mode VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  IF lower(p_update_mode) <> 'incremental'
  THEN
    RETURN;
  END IF;
  --
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORG' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
      -- NEXT entity table
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE
             WHEN t.creation_date > b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'update'
             WHEN t.creation_date < b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'add'
           END
      FROM data_view t
      JOIN batch_run_details b
        ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = t.entity_type
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

Comment: Basically there can be 2 mode one is full one is incremental. in previous question I asked for full where I took entire data of table. in this case it is incremental. By the way Can I convert the same into simple select query?  so that I can use it in UI and set the parameter there?

Comment: I actually put both the if block in this code. Now is it possible to write same in single block or in single query? because we are inserting data into single table only?  Can we manage in single query? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63513687/combining-2-if-block-and-creating-single-query

Comment: Hi, sorry I went to bed before. Your question already has an answer by Kevin McCabe that I find correct and almost exactly the same that I would do.

Comment: Hi, can you help me on this please   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541003/creating-json-from-oracle-database-table

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do to improve it is format it so it is readable.  Took me less time to format it than it took to write this sentence:

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Update_dynamic_entity(
p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
p_update_mode VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
    IF Upper(p_update_mode) = 'INCREMENTAL' THEN
      IF Upper(p_entity_type) = 'ORG' THEN
        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT p_entity_type,
               org_id,
               org_name,
               org_desc,
               'add'
        FROM   orgde
        WHERE  creation_date > (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);

        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT p_entity_type,
               org_id,
               org_name,
               org_desc,
               'update'
        FROM   orgde
        WHERE  creation_date < (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);
      ELSIF Upper(p_entity_type) = 'ITEM' THEN
        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT p_entity_type,
               item_id,
               item_name,
               item_desc,
               'add'
        FROM   itemde
        WHERE  creation_date > (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);

        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT p_entity_type,
               item_id,
               item_name,
               item_desc,
               'update'
        FROM   itemde
        WHERE  creation_date < (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);
      ELSIF p_entity_type = NULL THEN
        --Reading from org
        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT entity_type,
               org_id,
               org_name,
               org_desc,
               'add'
        FROM   orgde
        WHERE  creation_date > (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);

        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT entity_type,
               org_id,
               org_name,
               org_desc,
               'update'
        FROM   orgde
        WHERE  creation_date < (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);

        --reading from item
        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT entity_type,
               item_id,
               item_name,
               item_desc,
               'add'
        FROM   itemde
        WHERE  creation_date > (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);

        INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
                    (entity_type,
                     entity_id,
                     entity_code,
                     synonyms,
                     action)
        SELECT entity_type,
               item_id,
               item_name,
               item_desc,
               'update'
        FROM   itemde
        WHERE  creation_date < (SELECT max_last_update_date
                                FROM   batch_run_details
                                WHERE  entity_type = p_entity_type);
      END IF;
    END IF;
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

The second thing I would do is change the name of DYNAMICENTITYGTT to a readable name, DYNAMIC_ENTITY_GTT.  (actually code it in lower-case. I show it in upper-case because that is how it is in the data dictionary. I actually write all of my code in lower-case.)

Why are you inserting *two* nearly identical rows into DYNAMICENTITYGTT ('add', and 'update')?

The name of that table, with 'GTT' suggests it is a Global Temporary Table, so I'd expect you to actually do something with it, in the same session.

Comment: thank you Ed. actually where condition is little different for add and update. the table data will be read by java and will be injected into API. if update then will call PUT API else will call POST API with Data. target system is very bad so creating data keeping that in mind.Can i merge those 2 insert somehow using with or merge command? anthing like that?.

Comment: Ah, I missed the difference of 'greater than' vs 'less than' in the condition of the subselect that drives the insert.

Comment: @Ed thank you. Would it be wise if instead of creating procedure and calling it from java, I can directly use select query in java? I mean without creating procedure. I am actually calling this procedure from jdbc.

Comment: I prefer to keep all data processing as close to the data as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one insert statement, if you want. Just use `UNION ALL` to glue query results together. With `CASE WHEN` you can decide whether to write `'add'`  or `'update'`.

I am also making some assumptions here:

1. You don't only want to write rows for `creation_date` *less* or *greater* than `max_last_update_date`, but also when the two are *equal*.
2. Rows copied from `orgde` shall always have the entity_type `'ORG'` (not null when p_entity_type is null). Same for `itemde` and `'ITEM'`.
3. Rows copied from `orgde` shall get the `'update'`/`'add'` flag depending on batch_run_details where entity_type = `'ORG'` (not null when p_entity_type is null). Same for `itemde` and `'ITEM'`.

The procedure:

```
create or replace procedure update_dynamic_entity
(
  p_entity_type varchar2 default null,
  p_update_mode varchar2
) is
begin
  if upper(p_update_mode) = 'INCREMENTAL' then
    insert into dynamicentitygtt (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    select 
      'ORG', org_id, org_name, org_desc,
      case when creation_date > 
            (select max_last_update_date from batch_run_details where entity_type = 'ORG')
           then 'add' 
           else 'update'
      end
    from orgde
    where upper(p_entity_type) = 'ORG' or p_entity_type is null
    union all
    select 
      'ITEM', item_id, item_name, item_desc,
      case when creation_date >
            (select max_last_update_date from batch_run_details where entity_type = 'ITEM')
           then 'add' 
           else 'update'
      end
    from itemde
    where upper(p_entity_type) = 'ITEM' or p_entity_type is null;
  end if;
end update_dynamic_entity;
```

If you'd like this better with separate statements (i.e. no `UNION ALL`), I'd move the `WHERE` conditions outside the queries again:

```
  if upper(p_update_mode) = 'INCREMENTAL' then
    if upper(p_entity_type) = 'ORG' or p_entity_type is null then
      insert into dynamicentitygtt (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
      ...
      from orgde;
    end if;
    
    if upper(p_entity_type) = 'ITEM' or p_entity_type is null then
      insert into dynamicentitygtt (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
      ...
      from itemde;
    end if;
  end if;
```

Comment: Second code has one logical issue.  both if block will run. if it is org even then both condtion will become true. Requirement is if p_entitity_type is org then it should insert data for orgde, if it is item then it should  add for itemde. if it is null then both itemde and orgde.

Comment: That is intended. p_entity_type cannot be 'ORG' and 'ITEM' at the same time. So if it's 'ORG', only 'ORG' rows will be written, if it's 'ITEM', only 'ITEM' rows will be written, if it's null, both will be written. (The union query has the same logic, btw.)

Comment: ya it is clear now. Thank you @Thorsten. I was confused.

Comment: thank you Thorsten  . Would it be wise if instead of creating procedure and calling it from java, I can directly use select query in java? I mean without creating procedure. I am actually calling this procedure from jdbc.

Comment: It doesn't make much of a difference if you insert from Java or create a procedure and call that from Java, I think. I'd prefer the procedure. If at a time you want to change the code, you don't have to deploy an altered Java app. This also makes it easier to replace your Java app at a later time with something new, because the logic is in the database, while the app just calls a procedure.