# Combining 2 if block and creating single query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

Is there any possibility to merge both the if block and create single block from below. Both are logically connected.

If it is p_update_mode is FUll then I have to add all the data of table passed for P_entity_type . if it is incremental then I have put join condition to add selected add. also if p_entity_type is null then we have to add data for both item and org tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_dynamic_entity(p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                  p_update_mode VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  IF lower(p_update_mode) = 'incremental'
  THEN
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORG' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
      -- NEXT entity table
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE
             WHEN t.creation_date > b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'update'
             WHEN t.creation_date < b.max_last_update_date THEN
               'add'
           END
      FROM data_view t
      JOIN batch_run_details b
        ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = t.entity_type
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
  
 END IF;
 
 IF UPPER(UPDATE_MODE)='FULL' then
   
    INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( 
      SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              'add' action
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORG' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              'add' action
        FROM orgde
      )
    SELECT upper(entity_type), data_id, data_name, data_desc,action
      FROM data_view
     WHERE upper(p_entity_type) = entity_type
        OR p_entity_type IS NULL;
    END IF;
        
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(NOTE: this code is untested and I may be off a comma here or a parenthesis there...)

Those two blocks seem to only differ in the action column and a join, so you could eliminate the 2 IF legs and move the checking of p_update_mode into a CASE statement like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_dynamic_entity(p_entity_type VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
                                                  p_update_mode VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO dynamicentitygtt
    (entity_type, entity_id, entity_code, synonyms, action)
    WITH data_view AS
     ( -- ITEM table
      SELECT 'ITEM' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              item_id data_id,
              item_name data_name,
              item_desc data_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM itemde
      UNION ALL
      -- ORG table
      SELECT 'ORG' entity_type, -- This separates inserted values
              org_id,
              org_name,
              org_desc,
              creation_date
        FROM orgde
      -- NEXT entity table
      )
    SELECT upper(t.entity_type),
           t.data_id,
           t.data_name,
           t.data_desc,
           CASE lower(p_update_mode)
             WHEN 'incremental' THEN
               CASE
                 WHEN t.creation_date > b.max_last_update_date THEN
                   'update'
                 WHEN t.creation_date < b.max_last_update_date THEN
                   'add'
               END
             WHEN 'full' THEN
              'add' 
           END action
      FROM data_view t
           LEFT JOIN batch_run_details b
                  ON b.entity_type = t.entity_type
                 AND lower(p_update_mode )='incremental'
     WHERE (upper(p_entity_type) = t.entity_type OR p_entity_type IS NULL)
       AND (lower(p_update_mode) = 'full'
            OR (lower(p_update_mode) = 'incremental' AND b.entity_type IS NOT NULL)
           );
        
END update_dynamic_entity;
```

The query in your FULL block says we shouldn't join to B in this mode. So the LEFT JOIN clause only brings back rows when in INCREMENTAL mode, but should produce no rows for FULL mode.

This needs to be a LEFT join or we might not get any rows from your data_view that don't correspond to entities in B for FULL mode. In other words, if this remained a regular JOIN, your overall query would get zero rows in FULL mode because of the AND clause in the join.

Lastly, the AND filter in the WHERE clause at the bottom becomes necessary now that there is a LEFT JOIN. Without this, when running in INCREMENTAL mode, you would get EVERY row in your data_view REGARDLESS of there being a corresponding entity row in B or not. Even though you are joining on entity_id, the left join is going to bring a row back for each row in T even without a matching row in B, because that is what LEFT JOINs were designed to do.

All that said, you will have to decide if it is worth blending these two blocks. Just because you CAN, doesn't mean you SHOULD. Your performance may be better leaving it the way you have it--run some tests. Only you know the volume of data and the frequency of processing. You also need to consider the maintenance of your code, as the next guy/gal will have to figure out what is going on here.

Comment: Just a note for OP, it was mentioned in some of his previous questions. There is case with `t.creation_date > b.max_last_update_date` and `t.creation_date < b.max_last_update_date` but case with these dates equal should be handled as well just to avoid `NULL` value in `action` column that would be generated which might not be desired.